# Graphic Getting Cut Off: jQuery Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

My Navigation buttons are not displaying the entire HOVER and ACTIVE states on my Promotional Slider. The Circle needs to show, its getting cut off at the bottom and I do not know why.

Anyone Have any Suggestions?

Here is the Page: 
http://newsite.702wedding.com/aaaa-promo-slide-index.asp

The Problem should be apparent. JUST THE CIRCLES i am worried about. Rest works fine for me.

Thanks

Comment: "Hi! I'm Hilary, and welcome to Vegas weddings!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.paging a`, add some you need to add some `padding-bottom`.

So, replace your `padding` rule with this:

```
padding: 2px 4px 3px 8px;
```

---

To line all the numbers up correctly requires <strike>quite a few</strike> **millions** of changes. I've tested in Firefox.

Follow all of these steps:

- On `.paging`, remove the `letter-spacing` / `line-height` rules.
- On `.paging`, set these rules:

  ```
  padding-left: 6px;
  width: 236px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center
  ```
- On `.paging a`, set these rules:

  ```
  float: left;
  margin: 24px 0 0 32px;
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  width: 24px
  ```

Comment: Thanks Boss, I thought I tried that, must have overlooked it somehow.

Comment: Follow Up Question, How can i Center the "4"? its just like 2 pixels off, but thats enough for my boss to wigg.

Comment: I edited in the answer to that. I had to pretty much redo the way you were doing those numbers. But the upside is you can now use `text-align: center` to do the centering for you.